Wittgenstein and tautology

What does it mean to say that we can attribute neither being nor
non-being to the elements?  One might say: if everything that we call
“being” and “non-being” consists in the obtaining and non-obtaining of
connections between elements, it makes no sense to speak of the being
(non-being) of an element; just as it makes no sense to speak of the
destruction of an element, if everything that we call “destruction”
lies in the separation of elements. |25| One would like to say,
however, that being cannot be attributed to an element, for if it did
not exist, one could not even name it, and so one could state nothing
at all about it. But let us consider an analogous case. There is one
thing of which one can state neither that it is 1 metre long, nor that
it is not 1 metre long, and that is the standard metre in Paris. But
this is, of course, not to ascribe any remarkable property to it, but
only to mark its peculiar role in the game of measuring with a
metre-rule. Suppose that samples of colour were preserved in Paris
like the standard metre. So we explain that “sepia” means the colour
of the standard sepia which is kept there hermetically sealed. Then it
will make no sense to state of this sample either that it is of this
colour or that it is not. We can put it like this: This sample is an
instrument of the language, by means of which we make colour
statements. In this game, it is not something that is represented, but
is a means of representation. - And the same applies to an element in
language-game (48) when we give it a name by uttering the word “R” -
in so doing we have given that object a role in our language-game; it
is now means of representation. And to say “If it did not exist, it
could have no name” is to say as much and as little as: if this thing
did not exist, we could not use it in our language-game. What looks as
if it had to exist is part of the language. It is a paradigm in our
game; something with which comparisons are made. And this may be an
important observation; but it is none the less an observation about
our language-game - our mode of representation.

Wittgenstein, Philosophical investigations, part 1, paragraph 50.

Does Wittgenstein mean that to say that standard metre is one metre long is just to utter tautology? And therefore there's no use and, consequently, no meaning. Right?

What does “If it did not exist, it could have no name” mean here? I understand that it's not author's position, it's just mentioned by him. But what's the meaning of what he mentioned then?



One would like to say, however, that being cannot be attributed to an element, for if it did not exist, one could not even name it, and so one could state nothing at all about it.



Isn't this a perfect argument on the behalf of being of an element? Why then can't we attribute being to it?

Being "tautology" a technical concept introduced by W itself in the Tractatus, I think taht using it in the title can be misleading.

@MauroALLEGRANZA The standard metre from Paris is a physical object. And if you say that something is one metre in length, I may check it by using that standard metre. I'll just put standard metre alongside with the thing you claim to be one metre in length. And why it has no meaning to say that SM is one metre long? Because it's gonna be a tautology?

See C. G. Luckhardt, WITTGENSTEIN: INVESTIGATIONS 50 (1977): "“(T)he establishment of a method of measurement is
antecedent to the correctness of incorrectness of a statement of length,”*
Wittgenstein says, and so accepting something as the standard meter has
logical priority over using it to measure other objects."

Maybe the issue is: in the language game of measurement it does not make sense to measure the metre of Paris because it is the standard that legislativos what counts as the correct ascription of a measure of one metre to the lengthof a physical pbject.

The Paris metre is like the axiom of a system: you cannot prove it in the system.

Strictly speaking, one may, of course, say of the standard metre rod that it is one metre long. But Wittgenstein's point is that this is quite a different statement from saying that my dog's tail is one metre long. To say of the tail that it is one metre long is to say it is the same length as the standard metre rod. To say of the standard metre rod that it is one metre long does not mean that it is the same length as itself, since that would be a triviality. To say that the standard metre rod is one metre long is instead to say something about the concept and the measurement of length. It is a statement that plays a special role within the language game of stating the lengths of things. This is why Wittgenstein says that the
standard is a means of representation in the language game of measuring, not something that is represented in the system.
In context, Wittgenstein is talking about the concept of existence. Suppose we say (as the logical atomists did) that something 'exists' if it is an element, i.e. an atom in the logical sense, or is composed of elements connected together. And we say a thing is destroyed if its simple component parts are disconnected. Then it follows that an element cannot be destroyed since it has no component parts. But it is not some great metaphysical principle that there are indestructable things. To say elements exist becomes merely a statement about our concept of existence. Wittgenstein is pursuing his project of showing that what seem like metaphysical issues are really nothing of the kind and that many/most/all philosophical problems arise from our use or misuse of language.
Famously, Kripke disagrees. He holds that it makes perfect sense to say that the standard metre rod is one metre long. He considers this statement to be an example of a contingent a priori proposition. According to Kripke, it is metaphysically contingent, since the rod might have been a different length from the length it actually is, but it is a priori knowable, since we don't have to measure the length of the rod to know it is one metre long. There has been quite a bit of debate on this issue.

Saul Kripke, Naming and Necessity, Oxford, (1980). Especially, pages 54ff.
Nathan Salmon "How to Measure the Standard Metre", Proceedings of the Aristotelian Society 88 (1), 193-217 (1988).
W. J. Pollock, "Wittgenstein on The Standard Metre", Philosophical Investigations, 27 (2), 148-157 (2004).

(As I expect you are aware, the metre is no longer defined this way. It is now defined in terms of the distance travelled by light in a vacuum in a second.)

What you have said - that it is different to say that the international prototype meter is 1m long, than to say that a a dog's tail is 1m long - is defensible, but not what Wittgenstein said. What he said was that we cannot say that the international prototype meter is 1m long.

Note that using the current definition of the metre one could reformulate Wittgenstein's argument by replacing "what is the length of the standard metre rod?" by "what is the speed of light?"

@armand Yes, and of course light does have a speed.

@causative yes. But it's not the point. The point is that Wittgenstein argues it's meaningless (as he uses the word, ie it produces no new information about the world) to say "light crosses 300.000.000 meter per second" when precisely a meter is defined as "the distance light crosses in 1/300.000.000 second",  just like it's meaningless to say "the rod is one meter long" when a meter is defined as "the length of the rod".

@armand Neither are meaningless. Also Wittgenstein didn't use the word "meaningless," he said it could not be said that the rod has a length of 1m. But it can be said the rod has a length of 1m, and it can be said that light crosses 299,792,458 m in a second. These facts are not only meaningful, they are centrally important, if you're a physicist.

@armand Now, it is true that to say light crosses 299,792,458m in a second produces no new information about the world, because it is a fact that follows purely deductively from the definitions. But if from that you say it is "meaningless," you would  then be obligated to say all mathematical theorems are meaningless, which also follow purely deductively from the definitions and axioms. I certainly wouldn't agree with that. Anyway, again, in this passage Wittgenstein has nothing to say about whether it is meaningful, only about whether it can be said (and of course it can).

@causative we're not discussing physics. Displaying your knowledge about junior high trivia is fine and all but may I suggest you get interested in Wittgenstein argument and his theory of language, which are not new and have been commented extensively.

@armand Best to keep discussion about the topic and not make things personal.

@causative then be my guest and address Wittgenstein argument

@armand I'd love to continue to, but belittling someone else's argument as "displaying your knowledge about junior high trivia" indicates you aren't any longer interested in being fair to the other person's point of view. Nothing can be fruitfully discussed with that type of disrespect.


There is one thing of which one can state neither that it is 1 metre long, nor that it is not 1 metre long, and that is the standard metre in Paris.

Wittgenstein is referring to the international prototype meter, which was a physical object that looks like this:

Prior to 1960 (when Wittgenstein was writing) the international prototype meter was defined to be exactly one meter long. The same would be said of the standard kilogram. The standard meter was a real, physical, existing object, which Wittgenstein emphasizes by saying it is in Paris, so of course it had a length that you could measure, and that length was 1m.
Wittgenstein's notion of an "element" here is very vague and confused. He is trying to use the standard meter to justify his claim that "elements" can't be said to exist or not exist, but certainly the standard meter physically existed.
There could be things that we might decline to say exist or don't exist. Does the number 1 exist? Arguably, it's not meaningful to say the number 1 does or doesn't exist. (It is also arguable that 1 does exist, and it is also arguable that 1 doesn't exist). But there's no question about the standard meter in Paris; it physically existed and had a definite length.

Wittgenstein is rather saying something quite obvious: if to measure length is to compare to the standard meter, we cannot measure the standard meter, as what would we compare it with?  As simple as that: <>

@JulioDiEgidio You compare it with itself, and find the ratio is 1:1, therefore it is 1 meter. The same with the standard kilogram. (Though note this was only true in Wittgenstein's time; the definitions have moved on since then.) This isn't controversial unless you're really drinking the Wittgenstein kool-aid. Any (macroscopic) physical object has a measurable length.

I don't know why this is necessary, but suppose you wanted the length of the standard meter plus a penny laid down beside it. That would be easily measurable, about 1019.05 mm. Suppose you wanted the length of the standard meter plus a grain of sand next to it. Again no problem, maybe 1000.5 mm. So, why would you throw a NaN error when you take away the grain of sand?

Actually, from a philosophical standpoint, the rod is likely not to match itself if high-tech mensuration occurs. Subtle differences in temperature will results in subtle differences in length. One can aim for "standard conditions", but such a target is an engineering challenge that ultimately has a precision. Macroscopic physical objects have a measurable length, but the measurement is never exact or capable of being perfectly replicated. All measurements are approximate.

@Julio Di Egidio " if to measure length is to compare to the standard meter, we cannot measure the standard meter, as what would we compare it with?" The standard meter is indeed a normative fiction to establish an engineering convention, and does not exist in the sense of apples or rocks.

@JD Well, it's a little unclear exactly what was meant by the meter when it was defined by the international prototype meter. Arguably the international prototype meter was exactly 1m long by definition (provided it was at the right temperature), arguably its length could vary ever so slightly in comparison to the ideal. Either way, it certainly did have a length, and the length was very close to if not exactly 1m.

The question is not to argue wether the standard meter exists or not, but wether logical atoms (which Wittgenstein calls elements, as atomic elements of any statement) exist. Wittgenstein famously evolved from believing that affirming their existence makes sense (pre tractatus) to believing it does not (post tractatus) and producing his language games theory.
